# Changing volume in Windows Media Player without using the slider

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, windows-media-player

It seems that the only way to adjust the volume in Windows Media Player is to use the slider.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcuts.

<kbd>F8</kbd> will decrease the volume

<kbd>F9</kbd> will increase the volume

You can also use the volume mixer to change WMP's volume:

[image]

Comment: Actually, it's F8 and F9.

Comment: Must have been changed for WMP12, It's still F9 and F10 on XP. F8 is mute. Answer revised, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like [volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html).

> Volumouse provides you a quick and easy way to control the sound volume on your system - simply by rolling the wheel of your wheel mouse.
>   It allows you to define a set of rules for determining when the wheel will be used for changing the sound volume. For example: You can configure Volumouse to use your mouse wheel for volume control when the Alt key is hold down, when the left mouse button is down, when the mouse cursor is over the taskbar, and so on...

You can also designate how large the volume change jumps are.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of modern keyboards will have dedicated volume controls built into them, such as the keyboard I'm using at the moment. If memory serves then Windows XP will also respect these volume keys.

[Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Desktop 7000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-desktop-7000/WTA-00001)